# How to test if preprocessor symbol is #define'd but has no value?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

Using C++ preprocessor directives, is it possible to test if a preprocessor symbol has been defined but has no value? Something like that:

```
#define MYVARIABLE
#if !defined(MYVARIABLE) || #MYVARIABLE == ""
... blablabla ...
#endif
```

**EDIT:** The reason why I am doing it is because the project I'm working on is supposed to take a string from the environment through `/DMYSTR=$(MYENVSTR)`, and this string might be empty. I want to make sure that the project fails to compile if user forgot to define this string.

Comment: FYI, there is a difference between a variable and a preprocessor symbol and a variable.  Changed title to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Soma macro magic:

```
#define DO_EXPAND(VAL)  VAL ## 1
#define EXPAND(VAL)     DO_EXPAND(VAL)

#if !defined(MYVARIABLE) || (EXPAND(MYVARIABLE) == 1)

Only here if MYVARIABLE is not defined
OR MYVARIABLE is the empty string

#endif
```

Note if you define MYVARIABLE on the command line the default value is 1:

```
g++ -DMYVARIABLE <file>
```

Here the value of MYVARIABLE is the empty string:

```
g++ -DMYVARIABLE= <file>
```

#### The quoting problem solved:

```
#define DO_QUOTE(X)        #X
#define QUOTE(X)           DO_QUOTE(X)

#define MY_QUOTED_VAR      QUOTE(MYVARIABLE)

std::string x = MY_QUOTED_VAR;
std::string p = QUOTE(MYVARIABLE);
```

Comment: Hm, that breaks with `#define A "a"`.

Comment: As the pre-processor can add quotes auto-magically but can not take them away. It is unusual to see quotes in macros. So it is quite easy to get around this limitation.

Comment: But how would you handle `-DX="#"` or `-DY="a b"`?

Comment: This is quite clever, but it will break the build when `MYVARIABLE` is actually defined, since `EXPAND(MYVARIABLE)` will return non-integer value and compiler will stop at `#if !defined(MYVARIABLE) || (EXPAND(MYVARIABLE) == 1)`

Comment: @galets: Any identifier in a preprocessor condition is replaced as if it is a macro. If it is not defined then it returns 0. So the above code works fine as long as MYVARIABLE is EMPTY or MYVARIABLE is a valid identifier.

Comment: @galets: Try: `#define MYVARIABLE  Bob` for example works fine. EXPAND(MYVARIABLE) will return Bob1 which the preprocessor will replace with 0 as Bob1 is an undefined MACRO this will then fail the test 0 == 1 and thus the #if will not be expanded.

Comment: @Martin York: I think I know what my problem is. The string I tested with ends with "!", so this code fails to compile:

    #define MYVARIABLE Test!
    #if !defined(MYVARIABLE) || (EXPAND(MYVARIABLE) == 1)
    #endif

with: fatal error C1012: unmatched parenthesis : missing ')'

Comment: @galets: As does anything with a space, `||`, `#`, ... in it.

Comment: Or more precisely if it contains anything other than "[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*" The above will fail

Comment: @mchiasson: Hate to argue but it does. You must be doing somthign wrong.

Comment: **DANGER**: It does not work with `-DMYVARIABLE=abcd` if you have a `#define abcd 0` somewhere above your `#if` (because then `EXPAND(MYVARIABLE)` becomes `01` which **is** equal to `1`). If `MYVARIABLE` is to hold a user defined filename, you can never know whether the filename is actually the name of a macro defined to `0` (or `0x`, or `00`, ...) and the build will fail.

Comment: A slight improvement over Loki's solution is `#define NO_OTHER_MACRO_STARTS_WITH_THIS_NAME_`, `#define IS_EMPTY(name) defined(NO_OTHER_MACRO_STARTS_WITH_THIS_NAME_ ## name)`, `#define EMPTY(name) IS_EMPTY(name)`, `#if !defined(MYVARIABLE) || EMPTY(MYVARIABLE)`. This additionally works if `MYVARIABLE` is `0`, `0x`, or `00`, etc. (or the name of a macro defined to one of these).

Comment: There are a number of "gotchas", already described in the comments, which you should warn about in your answer, to save the unwary from trouble.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio 2013. Claiming there's a missing '. Do you have a workaround?

Comment: I came here looking for solutions to a similar problem. I wanted to test for the presence of the UNICODE preprocessor symbol within a macro. After a bit of tinkering and though, I concluded that this was a case in which a small inline function made more sense.

Answer (score 21):

I haven't seen this solution to the problem but am surprised it is not in common use
. It seems to work in Xcode Objc. Distinguish between "defined with no value" and "defined set 0"

```
#define TRACE
#if defined(TRACE) && (7-TRACE-7 == 14)
#error TRACE is defined with no value
#endif
```

Comment: Case when `#define TRACE -14` can be fixed
`#if defined(TRACE) && (TRACE+0 != -14) && (7-TRACE-7 == 14)`

Answer (score 12):

> I want to make sure that the project fails to compile if user forgot to define this string.

While i'd check this in a previous build-step, you can do this at compile-time. Using Boost for brevity:

```
#define A "a"
#define B
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(BOOST_STRINGIZE(A)) > 1); // succeeds
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(BOOST_STRINGIZE(B)) > 1); // fails
```

Comment: I think that is the answer. Making something fail on an undefined preprocessor macro sounds like an opposite of many questions here on SO.

Answer (score 10):

Mehrad's answer must be expanded to make it work. Also his comment

> /* MYVARI(A)BLE is undefined here */

is not correct; to test for an undefined variable, there is the simple test `#ifndef MYVARIABLE`.

After such test however, his expression leads to a correct solution of the original question. I tested that this code works, for undefined, defined but empty, and non-empty values of the macro MYVARIABLE:

```
#ifndef MYVARIABLE
    /* MYVARIABLE is undefined here */
#elif ~(~MYVARIABLE + 0) == 0 && ~(~MYVARIABLE + 1) == 1
    /* MYVARIABLE is defined with no value here */
#else
    /* MYVARIABLE is defined here */
#endif
```

The `#elif` statement `~(~MYVARIABLE + 0) == 0 && ~(~MYVARIABLE + 1) == 1`  works as follows :

- When `MYVARIABLE` is defined but empty, it expands to `~(~+0) == 0 && ~(~+1) == 1`, which works out `0==0 && 1==1` (the double negation ~~ being an identity operator).
- When `MYVARIABLE` is defined to a numeric value, say n, it expands to `~(~n+0)==0 && ~(~n+1)==1`. On the left hand side of `&&`, the expression `~(~n+0)==0` evaluates to `n==0`. But with `n==0`, the right hand side evaluates to `~(~0+1)==1`, with ~0 being -1 to `~(-1+1)==1`, then `~0==1` and finally `-1==1`, which obviously is false.
- When `MYVARIABLE` is defined to a non-numeric value, the precompiler reduces all unknown symbols to 0, and we get the previous case with n==0 once more.

My complete test code (save as file test.c) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("MYVARIABLE is "
#ifndef MYVARIABLE
     "undefined"
#elif ~(~MYVARIABLE + 0) == 0 && ~(~MYVARIABLE + 1) == 1
     "defined without a value"
#else 
     "defined with this value : %i", MYVARIABLE
#endif
    );
    printf("\n");
}
```

With the GNU preprocessor *cpp* you can experiment to see what code is produced:

```
# undefined
cpp test.c
#defined without a value
cpp -DMYVARIABLE= test.c
#defined wit an implicit value 1
cpp -DMYVARIABLE test.c
#defined wit an explicit value 1
cpp -DMYVARIABLE=1 test.c
#defined wit an explicit value a
cpp -DMYVARIABLE=a test.c
```

or output of compilation and execution (under some linux)

```
$ gcc -o test test.c ; ./test
MYVARIABLE is undefined
$ gcc -DMYVARIABLE= -o test test.c ; ./test
MYVARIABLE is defined without a value
$ gcc -DMYVARIABLE -o test test.c ; ./test
MYVARIABLE is defined with this value : 1
$ gcc -DMYVARIABLE=1 -o test test.c ; ./test
MYVARIABLE is defined with this value : 1
$ gcc -DMYVARIABLE=a -o test test.c ; ./test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
<command-line>:0:12: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
...
```

In the last run, where MYVARIABLE is defined as 'a', the error is not an error in the macro definition; the macro is correctly lead to the last case, "defined with this value...". But this value being 'a', and 'a' not being defined in the code, the compiler or course has to signal this.

In that way, the last case is a very good example of why the intent of the original question is very dangerous: via a macro the user can introduce any sequence of program lines in the code to be compiled. Checking that such code is not introduced, requires a lot more checking of the macro on valid values. Probably a full script is needed, instead of leaving this task to  preprocessing. And in that case, what is the use of checking it in preprocessing too?

Comment: This is a pretty cool trick, but I'm not understanding the purpose of the LHS of the #elif `~(~MYVARIABLE + 0) == 0` , wouldn't it be sufficient to simply have the RHS?

Comment: The second case of the detailed explanation of that statement proves the necessity of both sides.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `BOOST_PP_IS_EMPTY` macro like so:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/facilities/is_empty.hpp>

#define MYVARIABLE
#if !defined(MYVARIABLE) || !BOOST_PP_IS_EMPTY(MYVARIABLE)
    // ... blablabla ...
#endif
```

That did the trick for me. I shall add this macro is undocumented, so use it with caution.

Source: [preprocessor-missing-IS-EMPTY-documentation](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/preprocessor-missing-IS-EMPTY-documentation-td2663247.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can't since the preprocessor can only check for a numeric value. Your string compare is not covered by preprocessor syntax.

Comment: But any identifiers that are not defined evaluate to 0. So you can play little tricks with that fact

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this can be done. That being said, I don't see a need for it. When you make a preprocessor `#define` symbol, you should establish a convention that either you define it as 1 or 0 for use in `#if`, or you leave it blank.

Comment: "You should establish a convention" .. unfortunately, that's not always possible.  Take, for example, '__LITTLE_ENDIAN__'.  It's defined by some compilers, and not by others.  Most of the ones I've seen that define it define it as 0 or 1.  So, you can't just say "'#if __LITTLE_ENDIAN__'" :(    (And, ifdef doesn't solve the problem for you.)    Sigh, can't figure out how to get the two underscores before/after LITTLE_ENDIAN.  Even used backtick to quote as code.

Answer (score 2):

## For integer-only macros...

You can use a hack with no extra macros:

```
#if ~(~MYVARIABLE + 0) == 0 && ~(~MYVARIABLE + 1) == 1
/* MYVARIBLE is undefined here */
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

`#if MYVARIABLE==0`
My answer must be at least 30 chars, so that should do it!

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, often we want to check if a macro is *undefined*, is *zero*, or has an integer value *other than zero*:

```
#if ! defined(MYVARIABLE)
  // UNDEFINED:  MYVARIABLE is undefined
#elif ~ MYVARIABLE + 1
  // TRUE:       MYVARIABLE is defined and is empty or nonzero integer
#else
  // FALSE:      MYVARIABLE is defined and is zero
#endif
```

How does this work?

- if `MYVARIABLE` is empty then `~ + 1` evaluates to nonzero (true)
- if `MYVARIABLE` is nonzero (for example `1`) then `~ 1 + 1` evaluates to nonzero (true)
- if `MYVARIABLE` is zero then `~ 0 + 1` evaluates to zero (false)

This method works for any integer value for `MYVARIABLE`. When `MYVARIABLE` is the name of another macro, that macro's value will be used, as should be expected.

Note that if you just want to check if `MYVARIABLE` as a compile-time flag is enabled (defined and empty or nonzero):

```
#if defined(MYVARIABLE) && ~ MYVARIABLE + 1
  // the MYVARIABLE feature is enabled
#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that breaks if MYVARIABLE is a string.  All this discussion points out a fundamental flaw in C/C++: the inability to determine if a symbol is defined with a value.

Answer (score 0):

Warning! Dirty hack:

```
int xxx[1/(sizeof(PASSWORD)-1)];
```

Will blow up if password wasn't defined (in my case, aquired from an environmental variable that needs to be externally defined)