# Set macro to value, iff empty

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Essentially I got four cases in existing code:

1. macro ABC is unset
2. macro ABC is set, but empty: `#define ABC` or `-DABC`
3. macro ABC is set, and evaluates to true: `#define ABC 1` or `-DABC=1`
4. macro ABC is set, and evaluates to false: `#define ABC 0` or `-DABC=0`

I want the 1st and 4th, and 2nd and 3rd case to be the same:

```
#if defined(ABC) && IS_EMPTY(ABC)
#   undef ABC
#   define ABC 1
#endif

#if !defined(ABC) || !(ABC)
#   undef ABC
#   define ABC 0
#endif
```

How do I do `IS_EMPTY(X)`?

Comment: Same question here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781520/how-to-test-if-preprocessor-symbol-is-defined-but-has-no-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that only the values `0`, `1` or empty can occur you could use something like

```
#define some_impossible_macro 1
#define some_impossible_macro0 0
#define some_impossible_macro1 0

#define IS_EMPTY(X) some_impossible_macro ## X
```

Otherwise, for the general case this is a bit more complicated but doable. You could use `P99_IS_EMPTY` from [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr).