# How to tell if a #define has a value or not

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

As I understand with the C preprocessor you can use `#define` in one of two ways:

1. `#define SOME_VAL 3.4159f`
2. `#define SOME_FLAG`

I am writing a library and I am using #defines to for the user to parse in settings to do with compilation. My problem is I need to know which of the two aforementioned cases has been used.

Example:
`#define DISABLE_FEATURE` or `#define DISABLE_FEATURE false`.

Is there a way for me to distinguish these two or do I have to specify in documentation which to use?

Comment: The usual case is that those macros don't have a value. That's what's checked with `#if defined(xxx)`, it doesn't matter if a value is defined or not, the existence itself makes `#if defined(xxx)`  to become true.

Comment: `#ifdef xxx` or `#if defined xxx` or `#if defined(xxx)`

Comment: You can generate an error for the first (empty) define - will that suffice?

Comment: `#define HAS_VALUE_(m) sizeof(#m)>1` and then `#define HAS_VALUE(m) HAS_VALUE_(m)`. At this point, you can say `if constexpr (HAS_VALUE(SOME_FLAG))` and it will tell you if the flag is defined with a value or is defined to emptiness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do I have to specify in documentation which to use?

Technically no, you don't. But you should.

You can easily normalise on checking for false by doing this:

```
#ifndef DISABLE_FEATURE
#define DISABLE_FEATURE false
#endif

// later
#if DISABLE_FEATURE == false
...
```

Normalising on checking for definedness is a bit trickier because you cannot compare an empty macro with a value. But it is possible. You can use macro magic such as this (expansion magic borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3782064/2079303)):

```
#define DO_EXPAND(VAL)  VAL ## 1
#define EXPAND(VAL)     DO_EXPAND(VAL)

#if defined(DISABLE_FEATURE) \
    && (EXPAND(DISABLE_FEATURE) == false)
#undef DISABLE_FEATURE
#endif

// later
#ifdef DISABLE_FEATURE
...
```

I recommend instead to stick to one way and to document that. In particular I recommend checking for definedness, and to ignore the value entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a macro exists with e.g.

```
#if defined(SOME_FLAG)
...
#endif
```

See e.g. [this macro conditional reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional).

---

With that said, it's impossible to distinguish between an "empty" macro (like `SOME_FLAG` in your example) and a macro defined with the integer literal `0` as the replacemenent.

Also note that unless the macro can be evaluated by the preprocessor you can't compare its "value".

For something like `DISABLE_FEATURE` you can do something like

```
#if defined(DISABLE_FEATURE) || DISABLE_FEATURE != false
    // Feature *is* disabled
#else
    // Feature is not disabled
#endif
```

Comment: `#if !defined(DISABLE_FEATURE) || DISABLE_FEATURE == false` expands to `#if !true ||  == false` if `DISABLE_FEATURE` is defined as empty. That results in an error