# How "#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC" gets replaced by the preprocessor when there is no value for substitution?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, c++11, memory-leaks

I was using CRTDBG library to identify memory leaks in visual studio 2019. I need to define "#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC" macro for getting the line number of the leak occurs.
I am unclear that how the macro gets replaced when there is no value to be replaced ??

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <iostream>
#include <crtdbg.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    int *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr = 10;
    //free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I am a new to c/c++, Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

`#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` just tells the preprocessor that `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` is defined.

Code can later check if its defined with a `#if defined(_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC)`.

Note nowhere do we set or care or check what value its defined *to*. So doing something like `if (_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC == 2)` doesn't make sense.

But we dont need it to. It just has to *exist*.

Comment: There are some tricks you can do, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781520/how-to-test-if-preprocessor-symbol-is-defined-but-has-no-value

Comment: @Mike: On that case, then how the line number of the memory leak occurrence will be displayed ??

Answer (score 1):

It's simply replaced by the empty string. E.g.

```
#define FOO 1
std::cout << FOO+1; // expands to 1+1, outputs 2
#undef FOO
#define FOO
std::cout << FOO+1; // expands to +1, outputs 1
```

But typically these things are checked with `#ifdef`.

Comment: On that case, then how the line number of the memory leak occurrence will be displayed

Comment: @Meganathan: `malloc` will be defined as a macro, which expands to include `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

Comment: Where it will be defined as a macro ?? Inside crtdbg.h ??

Comment: @Meganathan probably yes. You can presumably search for it in there. VS comes with all the CRT/headers included so you can find it all if you look.

Answer (score 1):

This is the method I use and I prefer new and delete in C++：

```
#define new new(_CLIENT_BLOCK,__FILE__,__LINE__)
void  GetMemoryLeak()
{
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

And the program:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <iostream>
#include <crtdbg.h>
using namespace std;


#define new new(_CLIENT_BLOCK,__FILE__,__LINE__)

void  GetMemoryLeak()
{
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    int* ptr = new int;
    *ptr = 10;
   // delete ptr;
    GetMemoryLeak();
  
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

**Detected memory leaks!**
Dumping objects ->
C:...\Source.cpp(**16**) : {151} client block at 0x00F1CCB8, subtype 0, 4 bytes long.
Data: <    > 0A 00 00 00
Object dump complete.
The program '[10452] Project7.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: @Meganathan: Hi, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.